# Getting facebook public profile of a person in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-login

I am working on an ios app which requires Facebook Login.I have successfully implemented the login process.But now I am not able to find that how and where can i get the user's profile information like first name,last name, Profile Pic etc...My app has permissions to access firstName,lastName,Profile pic and Email.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Below is the code for getting person public_profile using latest Facebook SDK v4.0.1. You need to use FBSDKProfile to get person profile.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
        FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
        [self.view addSubview:loginButton];

        self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
        self.loginButton.delegate = self;
        [FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(profileUpdated:) name:FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification object:nil];

         }

    -(void)profileUpdated:(NSNotification *) notification{
         NSLog(@"User name: %@",[FBSDKProfile currentProfile].name);
         NSLog(@"User ID: %@",[FBSDKProfile currentProfile].userID);
    }

    - (void)  loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
    didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
                    error:(NSError *)error{

    }

    - (void)loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton{

    }
```

Comment: This function is not getting called at all
- (void)  loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
    didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
                    error:(NSError *)error

Comment: Please Make sure that you have included <FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate> in @interface .h file

Comment: yeah i already have included it but the function was not getting called.

Comment: your new edit let me extract the user id and name Thanks .Can u plz tell me how can i extract email and profile picture

Comment: The FBSDKProfilePictureView class provides an easy way to add someone's Facebook profile image to your view. Simply set the profileID property on the instance. You can set it to a value of me to automatically track the person currently logged-in.

Comment: how do you handle the result ?

Answer (score -2):

Use the Notification method so the when it receives information from facebook it ca call facebook delegated method

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleFBSessionStateChangeWithNotification:)
                                                 name:@"SessionStateChangeNotification"
                                               object:nil];
```

After that implement this method

```
-(void)handleFBSessionStateChangeWithNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
 NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];

FBSessionState sessionState = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"state"] integerValue];
NSError *error = [userInfo objectForKey:@"error"];
// Usually, the only interesting states are the opened session, the closed session and the failed login.
if (!error) {
    // In case that there's not any error, then check if the session opened or closed.
    if (sessionState == FBSessionStateOpen) {

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                     parameters:@{@"fields": @"first_name, last_name, picture.type(normal), email"}
                                     HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                  if (!error) {
                                      // Set the use full name.
                                      NSLog(@"first name and last name is %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                                                                               [result objectForKey:@"first_name"],
                                                                               [result objectForKey:@"last_name"]
                                                                               ]);
                                      NSString *firstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"first_name"]];
                                      NSString *middleName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"middle_name"]];
                                      NSString *lastName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"last_name"]];
                                      NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"email"]];
                                      // Set the e-mail address.
                                      NSLog(@"email is %@", [result objectForKey:@"email"]);


                                  }
                                  else{


                                      NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                  }
                              }];


        // [self.btnToggleLoginState setTitle:@"Logout" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else if (sessionState == FBSessionStateClosed || sessionState == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
        // A session was closed or the login was failed. Update the UI accordingly.
        //  [self.btnToggleLoginState setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // self.lblStatus.text = @"You are not logged in.";



    }
  }
}
```