# Getting user's Personal info from Facebook in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am quite new to objective-C and iPhone Development environment.

I am implementing Facebook login in my app to get User's name, Email and profile Picture. I have successfully implemented login Part and have received name and User ID of the person.

Now i want to get User's Email and Profile Picture from Facebook.But i am not having any Idea how to get it.I am using Facebook IOS SDK v4.0.

How can i fetch User's Profile picture and Email Id from Facebook when i am having User ID?

Comment: check this .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466795/getting-facebook-public-profile-of-a-person-in-ios-app/29466882#29466882

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111993/how-to-get-user-info-from-facebook-sdk-in-ios

Comment: @Shruti That's Ok i already tried implementing this link, but i got only first name and last name and no provision for getting Email ID

Comment: @SimerSarao i don't know how your are implementing that. I used the same code and i was getting email id too. Can you share your code for more clarity

Comment: @Shruti. Dear i am using Latest Sdk of  Facebook For iOS

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To get user Email ID you must ask permission for **email** while logging.

```
FBSDKLoginButton *loginView = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginView.readPermissions =  @[@"email"];
loginView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 150, 100, 40);
[self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

You can get user email Id in New SDK using GraphPath.

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"fetched user:%@  and Email : %@", result,result[@"email"]);
         }
         }];
    }
```

result would get you all the user Details and result[@"email"] would get you the email for logged in user.

To get Profile picture you can use

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=normal",result[@"id"]]];
NSData  *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
_imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

or u can also use FBSDKProfilePictureView to get profile Picture by passing user profile Id:

```
FBSDKProfilePictureView *profilePictureview = [[FBSDKProfilePictureView alloc]initWithFrame:_imageView.frame];
[profilePictureview setProfileID:result[@"id"]];
[self.view addSubview:profilePictureview];
```

Refer to :https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3#profile_picture_view

or u can also get both by passing as parameters

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                           parameters:@{@"fields": @"picture, email"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSString *pictureURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"picture"]];

                 NSLog(@"email is %@", [result objectForKey:@"email"]);

                 NSData  *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pictureURL]];
                 _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

             }
             else{
                 NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
             }
         }];
```

Comment: hi dheeraj i tried this but i am getting null in my email.

Comment: You must ask permission for email while logging.

Comment: i have done 
FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    loginButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];    
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];

in my viewDidLoad

Comment: is your email address verified ?

Comment: verified means ? yeah i have successfully logged in

Comment: where can i get result of the above i.e where can i read the name,email . i.e function name where i will get user profile

Comment: could you just try asking permission for email and not public_profile? like this self.loginButton.readPermissions =  @[@"email"];

Comment: what change you made?

Comment: Hi i made the Change specified by you in above comment

Comment: Attention: picture URL is under [[[result objectForKey:@"picture"] objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"url"]

Comment: parameters should not be nil to get email : see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31408714/976246

Comment: What is the object type from `id result` in the lasts sdk  this was FBGraphUser

Comment: What are all the fields (informations) returned in the `result` ?

Answer (score 22):

Sorry for this messy answer, this is my first answer ever. You can use FBSDK Graph request to fetch user's all profile infos and FBSDKProfilePictureView class to fetch user's Profile Picture easily.This code is for manually Facebook login UI.

Firstly, you must put this code where login process start:

```
 FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

    if (error)
    {

     // There is an error here.

    }
    else
    {
        if(result.token)   // This means if There is current access token.
        {    
            // Token created successfully and you are ready to get profile info
            [self getFacebookProfileInfo];
        }        
    }
}];
```

And If login is successfull, implement this method to get user's public profile;

```
-(void)getFacebookProfileInfos { 

FBSDKGraphRequest *requestMe = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil];

FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];

[connection addRequest:requestMe completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

      if(result)
      {            
        if ([result objectForKey:@"email"]) {

          NSLog(@"Email: %@",[result objectForKey:@"email"]);

        }
        if ([result objectForKey:@"first_name"]) {

          NSLog(@"First Name : %@",[result objectForKey:@"first_name"]);

        }
        if ([result objectForKey:@"id"]) {

          NSLog(@"User id : %@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]);

        }

      }

 }];

[connection start];
```

Get current logged in user's profile picture:

```
FBSDKProfilePictureView *pictureView=[[FBSDKProfilePictureView alloc]init];

[pictureView setProfileID:@"user_id"];

[pictureView setPictureMode:FBSDKProfilePictureModeSquare];

[self.view addSubview:pictureView];
```

You must add refreshing code to your viewDidLoad method:

```
   [FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];
```

Comment: facebookLoginButtonTouched is not getting called

Comment: I use custom Facebook Login button in my project. So "facebookLoginButtonTouched"  is my custom login button's "touched up inside" method. I am now editing my answer.

Comment: Most relevant answer in this thread. Far from Messy.
Thanks dude!

Comment: Despite some flaws in your answer, I put a plus for effort

Comment: 'GET requests for /me should contain an explicit "fields" parameter'

Comment: Are you sure that `enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:` __has__ to be added in the `viewDidLoad` method and not somewhere in `AppDelegate`?

Answer (score 6):

```
Hope This could Help You ..

- (IBAction)Loginwithfacebookaction:(id)sender
{


    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logOut];

    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Process error");
        }
        else if (result.isCancelled)
        {
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        }
        else
        {
            [self getFacebookProfileInfos];
        }
    }];
 }

- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error: (NSError *) error {

    NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);
    if (!error)
    {
        email =signIn.userEmail;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:email forKey:@"useremail"];
        NSLog(@"Received error and auth object %@",signIn.userEmail);
        NSLog(@"Received error and auth object %@",signIn.userID);
        if ( auth.userEmail)
        {
            [[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] plusService] executeQuery:[GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"] completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLPlusPerson *person, NSError *error)
             {
                 // this is for fetch profile image
                 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",person.image.url]];
                 NSLog(@"%@",url);
                 name= person.displayName;
                     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:name forKey:@"userNameLogin"];
                     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                NSLog(@"Name:%@",person.displayName);
                 [self callWebserviceToUploadImage];
             }];

        }
    }
}

-(void)getFacebookProfileInfos {

    FBSDKGraphRequest *requestMe = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"/me?fields=first_name, last_name, picture, email" parameters:nil];

    FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];


    [connection addRequest:requestMe completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        if(result)
        {
            if ([result objectForKey:@"email"]) {
                email = [result objectForKey:@"email"];

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:email forKey:@"useremail"];

            }
            if ([result objectForKey:@"first_name"]) {

                NSLog(@"First Name : %@",[result objectForKey:@"first_name"]);
                 name = [result objectForKey:@"first_name"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:name forKey:@"userNameLogin"];

            }
            if ([result objectForKey:@"id"])
            {

                NSLog(@"User id : %@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]);

            }
        }
        [self callfbloginwebservice];

    }];
    [connection start];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAccessToken.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKGraphRequest.h>
```

Add YourViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)loginAction:(id)sender {

   // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user
  //  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph


    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"email,name,first_name,last_name"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
                // Here u can update u r UI like email name TextField
             }
         }];


    }

}
```