# How can I found facebookSDK.framework on facebookSDK v4.0.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

So I've downloaded facebookSDK pkg, and I already installed it to on my document folder. But I can't find facebookSDK.framework inside the folder, I need it for my iOS project. Where I can find it?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure the framework you are after is **FBSDKCoreKit.framework**. If you are manually adding the framework this is found in the folder you have installed in your documents folder. This includes the ability to see:
 - Sharing
 - Login with Facebook
 - App Events
 - Graph API calls

Information found on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on an old app which is using FacebookSDK previous framework then you need to download that old version like 3.XX but if you are developing a new app and integrating new Facebook then you need to use FBSDKCoreKit.framework that is in v4.0.1

Some functions in never version are modified.

[For details study the Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

The above two answers are correct. Refer these if you want more clarification

1. [First One](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30390910/4140018)
2. [Second One](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29473323/4140018)